# Is there opensource data pipeline which can be used for updating vector tiles according to new commits?

Tags: openstreetmap, mapping

We currently have different open source components like for

Tile server->https://github.com/TileStache/TileStache

Styling and rendering->https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js

OSM to Postgres conversion->https://osm2pgsql.org/

All of the above components can be used to create one time MAP from country files.

My question is targeted to that, do we have any opensource component which can listen to deltas(which can be within an country) an keep on updating vectors tiles in cache?

If we have this there can be a full opensource suite which can be used for end-to-end map creation which all is driven by community.

Answer (score 1):

I would take a look at [OpenMapTiles](https://openmaptiles.org/). Under the hood, it utilizes **imposm** to convert an OSM PBF to PostgreSQL layers, and can then watch for diff files and update the tables accordingly.

While I do not personally use the full OpenMapTiles, I do use imposm to keep a regional extract up-to-date. I then use those layers to generate local print maps and PNG tiles, but I know that others use a similar process with OpenMapTiles to generate vector tile layers.

Answer (score 0):

> Tile server->https://github.com/TileStache/TileStache,https://osm2pgsql.org/

> Styling and rendering->https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js

> OSM to Postgres conversion-https://osm2pgsql.org/

> All of the above components can be used to create one time MAP from country files.

I am not sure why you assume this is only capable of creating a "one time MAP". The osm2pgsql manual pages clearly state osm2pgsql is capable of updating an existing database using the **--append** mode, in combination with the recommended "scripts/osm2pgsql-replication" or "pyosmium-get-changes.py" scripts in combination with **pyosmium**:

- https://osm2pgsql.org/doc/manual.html#running-osm2pgsql
- https://osm2pgsql.org/doc/manual.html#updating-an-existing-database
- https://osmcode.org/pyosmium/
- https://docs.osmcode.org/pyosmium/latest/tools_get_changes.html

I must admit I can't vouch for the other components in the stack you list, since I personally have never run a continuously updated stack, but it seems highly likely to me they will support updating as well.